# using fields of node and views_attach to display results

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I have the content-types "Product" and "Product Group". Products are generated by a huge CSV import. It has (among many others) the fields "rubrik" and "text1". Those fields exist as well in a "product group".

Now I want to attach a view (with views_attach) to product groups, that shows all products with the specified "rubrik" and "text1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a view with these settings:

Filters:
 - Node type is one of Product

Arguments:
 - Content: text1
 - Content: rubrik

Choose whatever fields and other settings you want.

I've never used views_attach but I think you can pass arguments to the view, and if you have token module installed I would hope that this would simplify that process.